# xml or sql for small android databases?

Tags: android, sql, xml, sqlite

I intend to make an app which is a sort of dictionnary for a slang/a dialect. There are not many words (less than 1000). To store the data, I have 2 solutions :

- storing data in a clean sqlite database (which I use to do in my apps)
- storing data in 26 xml files

according to you, which solution would be the most flexible and the most clean to use ?

Thank You

Comment: I guess a single database is the best solution over 26 xml files!

Comment: Use databases, useful for CRUD operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.For Better performance you must use sqlite insted of xml.
2.xml is more complex and you have to parse data by reading a tag, so its decrease performance and increase complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Using sqlite database has more flexibility over storing in xmls

1. you can manage the data easily. other operations like searching, adding more, or deleting and related operations will be easier
2. you wont need to handle the store operations manually. if you use xmls then you need to store those separately which will be more complex.

(to be hones i dont find any reason to use 26 xmls in your case)

Comment: 26 letters = 1 xml per letter ( i guess? )

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to only read from your files/database, you can use xml files, especially if you're going to cache the data during the life of your application. This won't make a big performance hit with your number of records/words and will be easier to manage during development. Also, check if you can use smaller number of files to simplify development)

You can also use text files (csv) for read-only data: they are easier to manage and read in the code.

If you are going to update the data or create related data (e.g. favourite words), Sqlite database will be better as it offers more flexibility and performance.